# this appeared when I tried flutter run

Tags: flutter, error-messaging

Error: The pod "Firebase/CoreOnly" required by the plugin "firebase_core" requires
a higher minimum iOS deployment version than the plugin's reported minimum version.
To build, remove the plugin "firebase_core", or contact the plugin's developers for
assistance.
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.

I tried removing the firebase core, increase the version of Flutter Facebook auth, updated the dependencies but still get the error- please help

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to remove the firebase core package the issue is that your minimum iOS deployment version is lower than the required version for the package so all you have to do is increase the app minimum iOS deployment version and you can do that with the following step:

Inside your project iOS folder click on Runner.xcworkspace and it will open your Xcode

[image: Xcode code picture]

Click on Runner under project to get this page then you will see the Deployment Target on the right panel as shown in the picture above

[image: Xcode image]

Then you can make use of the dropdown to increase the Deployment target
if 12.0 is the default you can increase it to 13.0 and run your app

Comment: hi thank you for replying :) I tried what you said but I'm getting the same message

Comment: i think the issue is with the firebase_core package minimum iOS deployment can you check if you are using the latest version

Comment: Try removing `ios/Podfile.lock` and `ios/Pods`, then run `pod repo update`, run `flutter clean` and then run your app (e.g. `flutter run`).